# Opening webpage and returning a dict of all the links and their text

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a webpage and return all the links as a dictionary that would look like this.

```
{"http://my.computer.com/some/file.html" : "link text"}
```

So the link would be after the href= and the text would be between the > and the `</a>`

I'm using `https://www.yahoo.com/` as my test website

I keep getting a this error:

```
'href=' in line:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Heres my code:

```
def urlDict(myUrl):
    url = myUrl
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    pageText = page.readlines()
    urlList = {}
    for line in pageText:
        if '<a href=' in line:
            try:
                url = line.split('<a href="')[-1].split('">')[0]
                txt = line.split('<a href="')[-1].split('">')[-1].split('< /a>')[0]
                urlList[url] = txt
            except:
                pass
        return urlList
```

What am I doing wrong? I've looked around and people have mostly suggest this mysoup parser thing. I'd use it, but I don't think that would fly with my teacher.

Comment: You mean BeautifulSoup? If your teacher knows anything about web scraping, he/she would strongly encourage it.

Comment: Well I'm doing a 5 week intro course and were doing python. Were going kinda fast so I'm surprised he hasn't mentioned it.

Comment: Yeah, in general I would recommend using a library purpose-built for doing this kind of thing, not rolling your own, unless the input example is a toy. As an example, this code totally falls down if there are multiple anchors on a single returned line, etc etc.

Comment: At the very least, you should use https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html to parse the HTML, it's part of the standard distribution and not a third-party library.

Comment: I guess i'll try to parse or use the mysoup thing, I have no clue how to though.

Comment: The documentation is pretty concise if you know what to search for... such as [`find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're attempting to compare a byte string to a regular string.  If you add `print(line)` as the first command in your for loops, you'll see that it will print a string of HTML but it will have a b' at the beginning, indicating it's not utf-8 encoding.  This makes things difficult.  The proper way to use urllib here is the following:

```
   def url_dict(myUrl):
   with urllib.request.urlopen(myUrl) as f:
        s = f.read().decode('utf-8')
```

This will have the *s* variable hold the entire text of the page.  You can then use a regular expression to parse out the links and the link target.  Here is an example which will pull the link targets without the HTML.

```
import urllib.request
import re

def url_dict():
   #  url = myUrl
    with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.yahoo.com') as f:
        s = f.read().decode('utf-8')



    r = re.compile('(?<=href=").*?(?=")')
    print(r.findall(s))

url_dict()
```

Using regex to get both the html and the link itself in a dictionary is outside the scope of where you are in your class, so I would absolutely not recommend submitting it for the assignment, although I would recommend learning it for later use.

You'll want to use BeautifulSoup as suggested, as it make this entire thing extremely easy.  There is an example in the docs that you can cut and paste to extract the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here is a [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) approach.

Feel free to replace `requests` with `urllib`, but `BeautifulSoup` doesn't really have a nice replacement.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_links(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
    return { a_tag['href']: a_tag.text for a_tag in soup.find_all('a') }

for link, text in get_links('https://www.yahoo.com/').items():
    print(text.strip(), link)
```